# Why is camera.LookAt, when camera is at (0, 0, 0), saying it turns -90 degrees about the axis to look at (1, 0, 0)?

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, camera

[image]

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pkaru0xn/12/

```
  box.position.set(1, 0, 0);

  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  camera.lookAt(box.position);
```

I position the cube at (1, 0, 0). The camera is positioned at (0, 0, 0).  According to the [three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/Camera.getWorldDirection) the camera looks down it's local negative z-axis.

So therefore I would expect that to look at the cube, it would rotate positive 90 degrees about the y-axis. How come the lookat function returns -90 degrees? Why does that work?

Comment: Read about the right-hand-rule as it applies to a right-handed coordinate system. That will tell you which rotation direction is positive and which is negative.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know that three js uses a right handed coordinate system, with the vector (0, 1, 0) being the default up. As shown in my drawing, with this up I would expect that the rotation to look at (1, 0, 0) from a forward looking down (0, 0, -1) would be 90 degrees, not -90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, the camera space is aligned with the world space. This means the camera sits at `(0, 0, 0)`, with an up-vector of `(0, 1, 0)`, and looking down the `-Z` axis.

The right-hand rule causes rotations to be applied relative to counter-clockwise. This means the rotation about the `+Y` axis with a positive value will cause the camera's lookAt to move toward the `-X` axis. Giving the rotation angle a negative value will make the camera's lookAt move toward the `+X` axis instead.

The code below uses both `lookAt` and `rotateOnAxis` to change the rotation of the camera. Notice that the looking at the object on the left corresponds to the positive rotation angle.

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true})
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
renderer.setSize(200, 200)
renderer.setClearColor(0x55ccff)

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, 1, 1, 1000)

const geo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(10, 32, 32)

const leftMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"red"})
const rightMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"blue"})
const frontMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"green"})

const left = new THREE.Mesh(geo, leftMat)
left.position.set(-50, 0, 0)
const right = new THREE.Mesh(geo, rightMat)
right.position.set(50, 0, 0)
const front = new THREE.Mesh(geo, frontMat)
front.position.set(0, 0, -50)

const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1)

scene.add(left, right, light, front, camera)

function render(){
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}
render()

document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  camera.lookAt(front.position)
  render()
})

document.getElementById("leftLook").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  camera.lookAt(left.position)
  render()
})
document.getElementById("rightLook").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  camera.lookAt(right.position)
  render()
})

const axis = new THREE.Vector3().set(0, 1, 0)
document.getElementById("leftTurn").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  camera.rotateOnAxis(axis, Math.PI / 2)
  render()
})
document.getElementById("rightTurn").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  camera.rotateOnAxis(axis, Math.PI / -2)
  render()
})
```

```css
.test input {
  width: 150px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.test {
  width: 100%;
}
.test:after {
  content: "&nbsp;"
  clear: both;
}
canvas {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/103/three.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<input id="leftLook" type="button" value="LEFT" /><input id="rightLook" type="button" value="RIGHT" />
</div>
<div class="test">
<input id="leftTurn" type="button" value="LEFT" /><input id="rightTurn" type="button" value="RIGHT" />
</div>
<input id="reset" type="button" value="RESET" /><br />
```